# how can i show jquery ui auto-complete categories list on focus event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete categories Widget.

how can i show all categories list on focus event?

here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/webspicer/pcf46/4/

i was tried to use following script for show all categories on focus event. but, it doesn't work for me.

```
$(this).data("ui-autocomplete").search($(this).val());
```

please give me the solutions asap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocomplete's [search](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method will display the autocomplete results.

E.g. the following code displays the autocomplete upon focus:

```
$("#checkValue").on('focus', function () {
    $("#checkValue").catcomplete("search");
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/pcf46/5/) (with your code linted/tidied).

Let me know if this works :)

*P.S. I recommend using the JSHint on your code from within JSFiddle, it looks like you were missing a semi-colon and had an extra comma..*

Comment: thanks for your response. but, i already add "minLength: 0," in the script. please see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/webspicer/pcf46/4/).                                                           $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "minLength", 0 );        where i can add this minLength in my script?

Comment: Yep, updated the answer. Check it out and let me know if it's what you were looking for :)